# How to sort text column by number sorting in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a column with address numbers (1, 1a, 3, 12b, ...etc).
I need to sort them as numbers (result as above), not text (such as 1, 1a, 12b, 3, ...etc).

What would be the sorting clause for this issue?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Your data is stored incorrectly, and if it grows to any large amount, any sorting you do on this incorrectly stored data will be VERY slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> Val(iif( /columnName/ IS NULL, 0, /columnName/ )) /order/